# Get an array of integer with Laravel query builder

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

I have this query :

```
$inError = DB::table('errors')            
        ->select('fk_fact')
        ->distinct()
        ->get();
```

And I want it to return an array of integers instead of returning an array of objects, I don't want to loop over all the results and push the values one by one...
Is there a way to do this with Laravel?

Answer (score 5):

Sure, you can use the built-in `lists()` method:

```
$inError = DB::table('errors')            
    ->select('fk_fact')
    ->distinct()
    ->lists('fk_fact');
```

You may need to tack on an `->all()` after the lists call.

Here's a tinker example from a database I happened to have up:

```
>>> DB::table('teams')->select('name')->distinct()->lists('name');
=> [
     "AFC Bournemouth",
     "Arsenal",
     "Aston Villa",
     "Chelsea",
     "Crystal Palace",
     "Everton",
     "Leicester City",
     "Liverpool",
     "Manchester City",
     "Manchester United",
     "Newcastle United",
     "Norwich City",
     "Southampton",
     "Stoke City",
     "Sunderland",
     "Swansea City",
     "Tottenham Hotspur",
     "Watford",
     "West Bromwich Albion",
     "West Ham United",
   ]
```

Answer (score 1):

**lists** was removed in newer versions of the query builder. You can use ***pluck*** now.

```
$inError = DB::table('errors')            
->distinct()
->pluck('fk_fact');
```

Comment: pluck()->toArray() returns a simple array